# Multiple arrays tensordot

Tags: python, numpy

I've got list of np.arrays like:

```
l = [array([0.2,0.3,0.5]),array([0.7,0.3])]
```

What I need to get outer product:

```
array([[0.14, 0.06],
       [0.21, 0.09],
       [0.35, 0.15]])
```

in general way:

```
array([[l[0][0] * l[1][0], l[0][0] * l[1][1]],
       [l[0][1] * l[1][0], l[0][1] * l[1][1]],
       [l[0][2] * l[1][0], l[0][2] * l[1][1]]])
```

But for any length of l (>= 2), so when len(l) == 4, I'll got 4-dimensional array.

My current approach is to use tensordot in for loop:

```
product = np.tensordot(l[0], l[1], 0)
for i in range(2, len(l)):
    product = np.tensordot(product, l[i], 0)
```

But I'm used that in Python code looks nicer. Have anybody some idea how to do nicer and faster solution?

The motive is that I need to get sum of element-wise multiplied two arrays:

```
result = np.sum(arr * product)
```

where arr.shape == product.shape. Maybe you, clever guys, can improve it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps more concise is:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: tensordot(x, y, 0), l)
```

Comment: If you're going to immediately name a lambda function, why make it a lambda?  The only real advantage is the ability to inline it.

Comment: Yeah - for some reason I started writing thinking a one-liner was going to be too long to be visible. Edited.

Comment: I didn't think of it like this, thank you. I will probably use this, it is definitely prettier, same speed.

Answer (score 0):

numpy has a great thing called [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), where it iterates through the arrays. so if you have an array that is x by 1 and multiply it by an array that is 1 by y, you'll get an x by y array. works just like matrices. So I am going to do everything you want in just 2 lines:

```
result = np.array((l[0])).reshape((1,len(l[0])))# resizing the first column to make it a 3 by 1 so that numpy broadcasting will work.
print result * l[1] # broadcasting the 3 by 1 by a 1 by 2 to result in your 3 by 2
```

And there you have it! quick and easy! I am going to put the entire code below for your convenience:

```
import numpy as np
l = [([0.2,0.3,0.5]),([0.7,0.3])]
result = np.array((l[0])).reshape((len(l[0]),1))
print result * l[1]
>>>>aray([[ 0.14  0.06]
 [ 0.21  0.09]
 [ 0.35  0.15]])
```

Comment: I think the OP already knows that `outer` or `tensordot` can easily handle the length 2 case, and was looking for a cleaner way to handle the case where `l` has arbitrary length.

Comment: DSM is right. Sorry if I wrote it in confusing way, but the len(l) == 2 was just example. I need it as was said for arbitrary length.